# Compute Cumulative Returns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, return, finance

If I have a vector of returns, is there a way to convert it to a cumulative returns vector in Matlab?

There is a very useful function in R called chart.CumReturns funcion from the PerformanceAnalytics package. Is there any similar function in Matlab?

Otherwise, I would like to do it manually in Matlab

For example, having the vector of returns:

```
r = [r1 r2 .. rn]
```

I would like to obtain the vector of cumulative returns such that:

```
rc = [rc1 rc2 ..rcn]
```

where:

```
rc1 = r1
rc2 = (1+r1)*(1+r2)-1
rcn = (1+r1)*(1+r2)*...(1+rn)-1
```

Since I'm new to Matlab, I don't know exactly how to structure a loop over this vector.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = r +1;
rc = cumprod(r);
rc= rc-1;
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Yep, this is better...+1

Comment: WILL NOT WORK in timetables. You can get partway there - define `f_1 = @x x + 1; rc = varfun(f_1,r);` Then, just try to `cumprod(rc)` and watch the true fail of ML timetables. In R, Python, even toys like Excel, it's a snap. So it's not just 'indexes start at 1' that make ML not worth it...the timetable functionality is *woeful* - if you want to do anything on a column of a timetable you may as well turn it back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a native function, but I know I can write one. : )

```
funciton cumVec = cumsum(InputVec)
    for ii = 1:size(InputVec), 2)
        tempVec = InputVec(1:ii)+1;
        cumElement = prod(tempVec);
        cumVec(ii) = cumElement - 1;
    end
end
```

I can't validate this right now, as I don't have MATLAB on this machine, but I think it's right

Comment: `funciton` might be a problem.